# searching, filtering with index in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

looking for help with this task. I need to create a list matching to a criteria found in the whole column and presented as list of rows.

[image]

If i use this formula `{=INDEX($B$2:$B$13,MATCH(F2,$A$2:$A$13,0))}` for List number and `{=INDEX($C$2:$C$13,MATCH(F2,$A$2:$A$13,0))}` for paint color, where cell `F2` contains number 2 and extending it, i get this result

[image: image2]

But what i would really like to get is something like this
Any other options?

[image]

Could you please help me out with formula to achieve it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

List number formula,

```
=INDEX(B:B, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($2:$13)/(A$2:A$13=F$2), ROW(1:1)))
```

Paint color formula,

```
=INDEX(C:C, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($2:$13)/(A$2:A$13=F$2), ROW(1:1)))
```

Fill down as necessary. Use an IFERROR wrapper to avoid #NUM! errors when you run out of matching records.